# Use links to hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a site with two images and some text. I need to code it so it shows the text on loading, but when a link is clicked, the text disappears and an image appears. And when a different link is clicked, the other image appears. This probably needs javascript/jquery. I have researched about changing the class so it does display:none but I cannot get it to work. Thanks. this is a mockup: http://amosjackson.com/index

Comment: what appens if the links are clicked again? (when images are shown) Must the images hide? In the title you say "hide", not "show"...

Comment: they are supposed to be navigation. imagine links to different pages with each picture/ paragraph on a separate page. that is the effect I am trying to get without making three pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hide()` and `show()` coupled with the `click` event.

```
$('#myLink1').click(function() {
   $('#image1').show();
   $('#text1').hide();
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. im very bad at javascript. could you check and see if there is anything wrong? http://amosjackson.com/index

Comment: I got it to work, I just needed to bind it to another event

Answer (score 0):

To use JQuery you have to download it from http://jquery.com/, put it where you want in your site, then you have to import it in the page where you want to use it.

Put this in your page head:
 `<script src="/path/to/jquery/jquery-x.x.x.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#homelink').click(function() {
            $('#contact,#tardis').addClass("invisible");
            $('#home').removeClass("invisible");
        });
        $('#bloglink').click(function() {
            $('#contact,#home').addClass("invisible");
            $('#tardis').removeClass("invisible");
        });
        $('#contactlink').click(function() {
            $('#tardis,#home').addClass("invisible");
            $('#contact').removeClass("invisible");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Change `href=""` to `href="javascript:void(0)"` in your menu links.

In your CSS put this class:

```
.invisible{ display: none; }
```

Finally set the `invisible` class on `DIV`s named **contact** and **tardis**.

Comment: now they're gone. but when I click the links, they do not reappear

Comment: @AmosJa have you put the **invisible** class only on images? what happens when you click the links? Have you updated the code on http://amosjackson.com/index ?

Comment: i did put the invisible tag on the images and I have updated the code. when I click the links, nothing happens

Comment: @AmosJa actually the issue was a little different from how you described it... It takes a bit of work to solve it. I've edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @AmosJa thank you for choosing the other answer... ;)